# Some emu8086 programs use org 100h without .model or .code, but still work?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I have just started learning Assembly. I see some programs needn't define
`.MODEL small`
`.CODE`....

They just org 100h and move to code  directly. So Is it not necessary? Can anyone explain?

Comment: Syntax depends on the assembler.  In NASM, you don't need `.model small` or `section .text`, but `org 100h` is a valid NASM directive.  Were you maybe looking at some NASM examples?  (Or maybe `.model small` is also the default for MASM and/or TASM?  `.code` is the default section/segment, but IDK what directives you need to give it to make obsolete 16-bit .com executables.)

Comment: I use emu8086. And I try applying 2 types and it still runs

Comment: EMU8086 will generate a DOS COM program if it sees you use org 100h. Otherwise if you use a model small, .code etc than it generates a DOS EXE program